# text-align center does not work on input tag

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have created a div which contains elements - img, btn and input. When I apply text-align center on the `.main` container, all the elements except the input tage does not get align in the center

It works well when i apply `margin:0 auto`

```css
.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-img {
  /* display: block; */
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /* margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; */
}

.search-input {
  display: block;
  max-width: 400px;
  /* margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; */
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #dfe1e5;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <img class="logo-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575936123452-b67c3203c357?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aW1hZ2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&w=1000&q=80" />
    <input class="search-input" type="text" />
    <button class="btn">Google Search</button>
    <button class="btn">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: remove display block from input tag.

Comment: *It works well when i apply margin:0 auto* Ok use that then?

Comment: I want to know why `text-align:center` is not working because by using this both the button and image are getting positioned in the center.

Answer (score -2):

```
.main {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;    
}
```

Do this instead

```
.main {
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Could you help me identify the error in this?

```
.main {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to align text into input tag you need to declare type of input...

```
    input[type="text"]
 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or in you case

```
   .search-inpu[type="text"]
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It is centering the input tag but post adding the buttons which were in the next line are getting placed in the same line as input box

Comment: This is centering the text inside the input tag. This was the question into the  title of the post. The author didn't write very explicitly. To align the item, just use `margin:auto;` nothing else.  Text-align is for text not for tag elements...

Comment: `<input>` tag is an inline-level element by default, and the text-align property primarily affects text alignment within block-level elements. That's why were aligned only these 2 elements.